# How can I access LogStream of Managed Application App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-app

We have a managed application published in Microsoft Partner Center, for preview audience.

We have both publisher and client tenants.
After installing the app into the client's tenant I can't access the log steam of the installed app from either publisher nor client tenants.

Adding Roles in Access Control IAM doesn't help.

When I'm trying to open Log Stream i can see only "connecting....".

If i turn on developer tools and open Network i see the "/api/logstream/" requests and "403 Forbidden" response. Adding a screenshot: [image: screnshot].

How can i fix this?
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's some sort of a bug as LogStream doesn't work on web portal, however it works in the VisualStudio Code.
Who might have thought, right ?

First, you should install Azure Tools. Next step is to sign-in with your account.

After that, you can open log stream:

Subscription / AppServices / Your App / Logs / Connect To Log Stream